# How to get selective file list in bash process

Tags: bash, shell, unix, grep

I have several hundred files in my directory `/foo/bar/`. I just want to grep the file list that does not start with `Not`, but ends with `.vcf`.

This code I have below selects all the files that ends with `.vcf`, but I just want to loop this bash code over files (`A_test.chr1.vcf`, `B_test.chr2.vcf` and `C_test.chr3.vcf`) from my files in `/foo/bar/`.

```
for i in /foo/bar/*.vcf;do
       do something
    done
```

my files in `/foo/bar/`

```
    A_test.chr1.vcf
    B_test.chr2.vcf
    C_test.chr3.vcf
    A_test.chr4.other
    Not_other.chr4.other  
    Not1_test.chr1.vcf
    Not2_test.chr2.vcf
```

Comment: @tripleee It is not a duplicate of the one you have marked.

Comment: Which part of it doesn't work for you?  Duplicates are acceptable if the *answers* are suitable, even when the questions are somewhat disparate (we get many questions where the OP doesn't know exactly what to look for).

Comment: @tripleee the question is a bit tricky. I need to grep files that ends with `.vcf` first, then avoid those files that start with `Not`. Order is important here.

Comment: And so `for i in foo/bar/*.vcf; do case $f in foo/bar/Not*) continue;; esac; : ... things; done` or equivalently `shopt -s extglob; for i in foo/bar/!(Not)*.vcf; do : ... things; done` as suggested in the top two answers in the duplicate question.

Answer (score 0):

Either:

```
find /foo/bar -type f \( ! -name "Not*" -iname "*.vcf" \) | xargs DoSomething
```

or

```
find /foo/bar -type f \( ! -name "Not*" -iname "*.vcf" \) -exec DoSomething {} \;
```

The syntax:

```
for i in $(find /foo/bar -type f \( ! -name "Not*" -iname "*.vcf" \); DoSomething; done
```

would work too, but it is dangerous if your files have whitespaces in their filename.

---

### Edit

Basically everything is based on the find command.

```
mkdir -p foo/bar
cd foo/bar/
touch A_test.chr4.vcf  A_test.chr4.other Not_other.chr4.other Not1_test.chr1.vcf
cd ../..
find foo/bar/ -type f \( ! -name "Not*" -iname "*.vcf" \)
```

And the result is:

```
./A_test.chr4.vcf
```

Comment: Sorry this did not work

Comment: You could tell us what doesn't work. I updated my answer to give you more details. It should help!

Comment: Maybe post to the duplicate instead; it doesn't seem to have this variant.

Comment: @tripleee: Done! Hope this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36470940/882697

Answer (score -2):

try the next:
`find ./foo/bar/ -type f -name *.vcf | while read -r line; do echo $line & done;`

Comment: How are you avoiding `Not` files?

Comment: What's with the `&`?

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.